# Sort instances of a loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hello I've been learning Laravel this past few weeks. Though I encounter a problem of sorting each instances of this loop in accordance to the value of this ----> **$post->user->receivedUpvotes->count() - $post->user->receivedDownvotes->count()**

```xml
@foreach($posts->unique('user_id') as $post)   
  <a href="{{ route('users.posts', $post->user) }}" class="font-bold text-xl">
    {{ $post->user->name }}
  </a>
  <p class="mb-4">
    <span class="mr-3 text-gray-600">Karma Gained: </span>
    <span class="text-green-700 font-semibold">
      {{ $post->user->receivedUpvotes->count() - $post->user->receivedDownvotes->count() }}
    </span>
  </p> 
@endforeach
```

I'm kinda stuck on finding the solution to sort them as their value is not in database

My models goes like this

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function upvotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Upvote::class);
}

public function receivedUpvotes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Upvote::class, Post::class);
}

public function downvotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Downvote::class);
}

public function receivedDownvotes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Downvote::class, Post::class);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function upvotedBy(User $user)
{
    return $this->upvotes->contains('user_id', $user->id);
}

public function downvotedBy(User $user)
{
    return $this->downvotes->contains('user_id', $user->id);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function upvotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Upvote::class);
}

public function downvotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Downvote::class);
}
```

and both **Upvote.php and Downvote.php** has this

```
use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];
```

This is my controller **DashboardController.php**, currently I only put have it to show the latest posts

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $posts=Post::latest()->with(['user','upvotes'])->get();
        return view ('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts]);    
    }        
}
```

Comment: Can you try to add a function in `User.php`
```
public function getNetVotesAttribute() {
    return $this->receivedUpvotes()->count() - $this->receivedDownvotes()->count();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentally click enter just now, refer to my edited comment above, then you can sort user by the function, or if you add "netVotes" to the $appends array in User.php, you can directly sort using netVotes. e.g. `$posts = Post::all()->sortBy(function($post) { return $post->user->netVotes; });` or f you didn't add to the $appends array, `$posts = Post::all()->sortBy(function($post) { return $post->user->getNetVotesAttribute(); });`

Comment: It seems it does the trick! Thanks a lot for your help, I learned the idea behind the function and sorted it in descending manner!

Comment: Glad that it helps! Maybe I will add as an answer for future references as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In User.php, add

```
public function getNetVotesAttribute() 
{
    return $this->receivedUpvotes()->count() - $this->receivedDownvotes()->count(); 
}
```

then you can sort your users using the function, or if you add "netVotes" to the `$appends` array in User.php, you can directly sort using netVotes. e.g.

```
$posts = Post::all()->sortBy(function($post) { 
    return $post->user->netVotes; 
});
```

or if you didn't add to the `$appends` array,

```
$posts = Post::all()->sortBy(function($post) { 
    return $post->user->getNetVotesAttribute(); 
});
```